# jQuery plugin making a API url relative to included js file rather than host

Tags: jquery, api, relative-path

Hi currently I am working on a jQuery plugin in which I make an API call. Rather than hard coding the URL for the API, I would like it to be relative in terms of the URL of the JS file of the plugin

So say I have the following set up

Page loading the file

```
http://mydomain1.com
```

In that page I load

```
<script src="http://mydomain2.com/Scripts/myPlugin.min.js">
```

In that JS file, I load the API url as

```
api_endpoint: "/myApi/api/v1",
```

I was hoping this would resolve to

```
http://mydomain2.com/myApi/api/v1
```

but it resolves to

```
http://mydomain1.com/myApi/api/v1
```

Is there anyway in Javascript I can set the domainname relative to the JS File loading the script rather than the page itself ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per my understanding of your problem, you want url of your external file as a base URL. So you can use below code to access that:

1. Captured all the script files of the document
2. Defined index to get the script file and refined any query string from the url
3. Now used split and slice to remove last directory name(folder name) and join to make complete url

...

```
var scriptTags = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
var filterPath = scriptTags[0].src.split('?')[0];      // Hopping your script is on first place of dom and removing any ?query
var scriptFilePathUrl = filterPath.split('/').slice(0, -1).join('/');
alert(scriptFilePathUrl);
```